# GWT's equivalent of JSF Navigation Handler

Tags: jsf, gwt

What is the preferred way of implementing GWT application that has centrally managed navigation (like custom JSF NavigationHandler or Front Controller pattern) that routes between application forms based on their outcomes and current navigation state and enforces that only valid navigation can occur ?

Are there any good GWT frameworks that support this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/). 
It supports navigation, handling invalid navigation urls, building navigation state via tokens, etc
However I am not sure if it has all the features of JSF NavigationHandlers.